# ChartJS in NextJS throws error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

so I am trying to add graphs using ChartJS for my NextJS application. However, I seem to have issues rendering it. I also followed other tutorials and/or articles but it seems that I get the same error.

The error I get is this:

```
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

I am not sure why I am getting that error since I am not using `useRef` hook in my code.

Here is my code for `root/pages/admin/home.js`

```js
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import LineGraph from '../../components/admin/line'

export default function Home() {

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Head>
                <title>Create Next App</title>
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>

            <main>
                <LineGraph />
            </main>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is my code for the LineGraph `root/components/admin/line.js`

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

const data = {
  labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'My First dataset',
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,0.4)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointBorderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    }
  ]
};

const LineGraph = () => {
  return (
    <canvas>
      <h2>Line Example</h2>
      <Line
        id="lineChart"
        data={data}
        width={400}
        height={400}
      />
    </canvas>
  );
}

export default LineGraph;
```

PS: If this question is duplicated, pls drop the link and I'll give it a go. Thank you very much for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured it out. It has something to do with the package version. Inside my `package.json` file, I have the following dependencies:

```json
"dependencies": {
        "next": "12.3.1",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0",
        "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
        "react-chartjs-2": "^2.9.0"
}
```

To make it work, I had to manually install `chart.js` and `react-chartjs-2` with a specific version. So, my graph finally works and my `package.json` looks like this:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
    "next": "12.3.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^4.3.1",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
```

Comment: Same for me, but still raise error

Comment: @János make sure your nextjs version supports the chartjs and react-js-2 versions you installed. Mine worked after I did that

Answer (score 0):

First since you are not using the `useRef` you can remove the import.

Your code likely fails on that you put your HTML inside of a `canvas` element which is not something you should do.

React-chartjs automatically will create the canvas tag for you. So you should change your canvas tag to be a div or even cleaner a fragment

```
const LineGraph = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Line Example</h2>
      <Line
        id="lineChart"
        data={data}
        width={400}
        height={400}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I did what you recommended and I still got the error on my end